# Altering syntax highlighting for a particular expression

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, cc-mode

In c-mode, I would like all lines beginning with

```
exec sql
```

to have that expression grey and the rest of the line in the default face.  How might I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The following will do something similar to what you asked for.

```lisp
(let ((re "^[   ]*\\(exec sql\\)\\(.*\\)$"))
    (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode `((,re 1 font-lock-preprocessor-face t)))
    (font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode `((,re 2 font-lock-string-face t))))
```

The numbers represent subexpression matches, and the `t` mean that already present fontification should be overridden.  Have a look at the documentation of `font-lock-keywords`.